# Remove character string only if it occurs at the end of a string

Tags: r, string

I want to remove the final characters "txt" if they exist at the end of a character string. However, sometimes, the characters can be found at other locations of the string also.

i.e. I would like to remove `txt` from `"/some-text-here/txt"` but not from `"/txt-not-to-remove-text/"` since in the last example it does not occur after the last occurance of the `/`

So, I only want to extract `txt` if it occurs at the end of the string.

```
string = c("/some-text-here/txt",
           "/some-other-text-here/txt",
           "/txt-not-to-remove-text/",
           "/txt-another-line-of-text/txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `trimws`

```
trimws(string, whitespace = "/txt", which = 'right')
```

-output

```
[1] "/some-text-here"           "/some-other-text-here"  
[3]   "/txt-not-to-remove-text/"  "/txt-another-line-of-text"
```

---

Or using `sub` and specify the end (`$`) of the string

```
sub("/txt$", "", string)
```